# Add a custom page to Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Probably my question is a bit dumb as there is a lot of documentation about routing. The problem is, I am not an angular specialist, so I am missing a bit of context.

I would like to add a custom sub page (http://localhost:4200/image-upload) to spartacus. The Header and Footer should be the same. Just the content should be an upload form.

**Where and how do I configure the route?**

Comment: please show what you have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a new content page in CMS with page label `/image-upload` (with the leading slash). Spartacus routing should handle it OOTB. https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/adding-and-customizing-routes/
2. Add a layout config only if your page has custom layout https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/page-layout/#configuring-the-layout
3. Implement Angular CMS components that should appear on this page and configure mapping from CMS component type to the implementation https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/customizing-cms-components/#page-title